# Fetch last x records for every id in list

Tags: mysql

So I have the following 4 tables (unnecessary columns removed):

```
match_player:
+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
| match_id | metric_id | player_id | team  | elo  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+------+
|        1 |       100 |         1 | Alpha | 1140 |
|        2 |       101 |         3 | Beta  | 1140 |
|        3 |       102 |         2 | Beta  | 1200 |
|        3 |       103 |         3 | Alpha | 1132 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+-------+------+

match:
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+-------------+------------+
| match_id | start               | end                 | mode | ranked | goals_alpha | goals_beta |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+-------------+------------+
|        1 | 2016-03-21 04:07:41 | 2016-03-21 04:25:26 | 5v5  |      1 |           4 |          6 |
|        2 | 2016-03-21 03:48:03 | 2016-03-21 04:06:41 | 5v5  |      0 |           5 |         10 |
|        3 | 2016-03-21 03:06:37 | 2016-03-21 03:31:06 | 5v5  |      1 |           7 |         13 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+-------------+------------+

player:
+-----------+----------+
| player_id | name     |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | Player 1 |
|         2 | Player 2 |
|         3 | Player 3 |
+-----------+----------+

metric:
+-----------+--------+-------+
| metric_id | passes | goals |
+-----------+--------+-------+
|       100 |     10 |     1 |
|       101 |     12 |     0 |
|       102 |      4 |     5 |
|       103 |      9 |     3 |
+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Now, as the title suggests, I would like to retrieve the last *x* matches for **each** player who's player_id is in a list retrieved by a previous query. I know how to get **1** player's last *x* matches, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the matches for **more than 1** player (of course I could use `UNION` to combine the results of each query for each single player, but I doubt that's efficient when dealing with 100+ players).

It would be great if a "simple" solution were found. If not, I guess I'll have to create another table `last_30_matches` or so and have that be updated when a match is added to the `match` table.

Thanks in advance to everybody who takes their time to look into this.

**EDIT:**

```
Query to select last x matches for 1 player:

SELECT
  *
FROM
  `match`
JOIN
  match_player ON match_player.match_id = `match`.`match_id`
JOIN
  metric ON metric.metric_id = match_player.metric_id
JOIN
  player ON player.player_id = match_player.player_id
WHERE
  player.player_id = <id>
ORDER BY
  `match`.end DESC
LIMIT x
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Comment: Please post your current query that fetches it for 1 player.

Comment: Updated question with the query

Comment: Did you try `IN` like `player.player_id IN(1, 2, 3, 4)`;

Comment: I did, but then applying the `LIMIT x` limits the **total** amount of returned matches, not the amount of matches **per player**

Comment: Well, the easiest way to do that is if you're using some code (like php, c#, etc.) then iterate though the players and query it separately, or you probably can do that in a mysql function too.